# Calculate position regardless of containing block

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a `<table>` within a couple `<div>` tags:

```
<div class=outer>
  <div class=inner>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

If get the position of a row w/ jQuery's `$.fn.position` function:

```
console.log($('tr:first').position().top);
```

It will return a different value depending upon whether I set `div.inner` to `position: relative` ([example](http://jsbin.com/opakew/8/edit)).  I believe this is because the row's [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#containing-block) is different in each case.

I need to calculate the row's position relative to the body regardless of wether `div.inner`'s position is set to `relative`.  Is there an elegant way to accomplish this?  Or will I need to ascend the DOM tree, checking whether each ancestor is `position: relative`, and adding an offset based on that?

Comment: Wouldn't `$.offset()` give you the coordinates you're searching for? Its location is '[relative to the document](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)'

Comment: Did that provide the solution you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you console.log($('tr:first').offset().top);